# Local/Remote hosts in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

Given a cluster, how exactly are different nodes labelled as remote/local? Does it depend on per query basis? 
Currently, I am thinking like this->For each query that the client sends to the Cassandra cluster, a coordinator node will be selected(based on the load balancing policy). All nodes which belong to the same datacenter as the coordinator node will be called the local nodes and rest all nodes will be the remote nodes for the given query.
Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's correct from coordinator perspective.  But there is also a driver perspective - when you use a driver with DC-aware policy, you specify what DC is local for you (in C++ via `cass_cluster_set_load_balance_dc_aware` function), and this data is used by driver to select correct node (based on other policies).